# Edits under 6 characters cannot be previewed in iOS app

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ios-app, markdown-preview

Users are not able to preview edit suggestions under 6 characters in the iOS app. The SE app gives an error stating the edit must be at least 6 characters.

While this limitation makes sense for submitting edits, I'm not so sure it makes sense for previewing edits.

[image: Request failed: Edits must be at least 6 characters]

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: I think preview works through same mechanism like an actual posting. That's why you can't see it.